# Excel-VBA conditional formatting with vlookup: why does my argument change ($B1 to $B1048573)

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm kinda confuded, 'coz i can't find a way to prevent excel from changing...
But let's start at the beginning.

I've following code for my macro:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="DBM", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "='Sheet A'!C35:C39"

With Worksheets("Sheet B").Range("$B:$B").FormatConditions _
    .Add(Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlExpression, Formula1:="IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP($B1;DBM;5;FALSE));TRUE;FALSE)")
    With .Interior
        .ColorIndex = 3
    End With
End With
```

This works kinda, but not for my fully needs.
It automatically changes the `$B1` argument within my vlookup functions changes to `$B1048573` - 
That's why the wrong lines are formatted (background color red). If i manually change it back to `$B1` it will be absolutely correct.

So I tried to add this in my macro:

```
Worksheets("Sheet B").Range("$B:$B").FormatConditions(1) _
    .Modify Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlExpression, Formula:="IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP($B1;DBM;5;FALSE));TRUE;FALSE)")
```

Unfortunetaly it does the change ($B1048573) once again.

Does any1 have an idea how to fix it? Or do I really have to change it back manually everytime i use the macro?

Comment: Do you just want to do this for each cell in range (B:B) that matches some condition?

Comment: Thanks Rory. Seems this was too easy :p This fix works :p

Answer (score 0):

### Comment by Rory

> Select B1 first

This was pretty much the solution.
Just wanted to add this here, so everyone with the same issue can immediatly find the answer.

Thanks Rory.